# multiple authors format for saving space

Tags: paper-submission, authorship

I am submitting the final version for an ACM sponsored conference and I am dubious about what would be the correct format to include multiple authors (with multiple I mean more than tree). The ACM template has the following author heading:

[image]

in which I need to add another author, but If I do that in a new line (apart that the Word template moves horrible to the left side) then I will be out of the limits of pages that the conference established.

I would like to know, and maybe it sounds like a silly question if I can do the following:

[image]

The four authors belong to the same institution, and the only thing that changes is the email. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: This is a great question for the program committee chair.

Comment: (ACM asks for _telephone numbers_ now? Dear lord.)

Comment: @JeffE, that surprised me too. I might object to that, actually.

Comment: @buffy you can always give the main department number

Comment: @StrongBad - I would have suggested giving the number of the payphone downstairs by the elevator, but sadly those don’t exist anymore...

Comment: Give them the number of the ACM president.

Answer (score 1):

The conference chair might tell you otherwise, but you could probably do it. I've even seen (with ACM conferences) putting both emails on one line as

(author1, author2)@institution.edu

But that assumes the email addresses are easy to associate with a person's name.

But there is no particular reason not to submit it with your best effort as to layout. Maybe it gets edited after review in any case.

But also note that most people in CS expect that the author listing will be alphabetical. But the "true" meaning of that is "the order doesn't matter and we all built this together." So, it might not be a problem.

Comment: _most people in CS expect that the author listing will be alphabetical_ — Only in the more theoretical areas of CS.  More experimental/engineering areas of CS use author ordering as a signal.

Comment: @JeffE, yes, I keep forgetting that it isn't uniform. OTOH, in my work which isn't especially theoretical we just do alphabetical. Software process (agile...), pedagogy, ...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... I'm not familiar with ACM standards, but in engineering journals I've come across exactly what may be asking for... its all in a single column, then all the (same-institution) authors simply get attributed to one university address and only the corresponding author (denoted by *) has email/address details below.

It would be most appropriate to ask the conference chair or your advisor ASAP if you can deviate from the SIG format or how they would approach your situation. Don't assume anyone will edit it upon submission, if anything, submit now and ask later :)